# How to make sure my application is CalDAV compliant?

Tags: java, calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar, caldav

I am currently trying to design a Calendar application in Java. Then I want to integrate it with Google Calendar.

It will contain APIs to create and manage calendar events and working hours for the user.

I read that for integration with Google calendar, my application should comply with CalDAV protocol.

I am trying to understand what CalDAV is and how can I use it to help my application sync with Google Calendar. The document I am referring is [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/pdfrfc/rfc4791.txt.pdf). There are a lot of other references/documents which it refers to - iCalendar, WebDAV etc. So far what I have understood is that CalDAV is an extension of WebDAV, which is a file read/write protocol. And iCalendar is a file format. I have seen iCalendar used in mail invitations (.ics files).

But I don't understand how to use all of this in my application and how to implement it?

Comment: CALDAV is for scheduling.  It uses the icalender .ics format.   If you want google calendar uses to be able to subscribe to your calendar feeds, then you issue these in .ics file format as per https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545.n   You can test this with other calendar applications that allow one to share calendars.  There are ics validators which are useful but not necessarily 100% gurarateed, they sometimes report on different errors.  Use them but also test that the majors (apple, google,outllook  etc) will subscribe to your ics url

Answer (score 1):

For Google's CalDAV support details see [CalDAV guide](https://developers.google.com/calendar/caldav/v2/guide).